# Saving image throws an unexpected keyword argument 'strict' error in offline plotly in python

Tags: python, plotly

I am using offline plotly to generate some plots and want to save them in my machine (MAC OS) , I followed the below steps.

```
npm install -g electron@1.8.4 orca
pip install psutil requests
```

and then save the plot like below :

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import plotly.offline as py
py.init_notebook_mode(connected=False)
np.random.seed(1)

N = 100
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
sz = np.random.rand(N) * 30

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    mode="markers",
    marker=go.scatter.Marker(
        size=sz,
        color=colors,
        opacity=0.6,
        colorscale="Viridis"
    )
))

fig.show()


fig.write_image("fig1.png")
```

I encountered an error

> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in
>   send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
>       290         return response
>       291 
>   --> 292     def get_connection(self, url, proxies=None):
>       293         """Returns a urllib3 connection for the given URL. This should not be
>       294         called from user code, and is only exposed for use when subclassing the
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py
>   in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect,
>   assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, **response_kw)
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py
>   in _get_conn(self, timeout)
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py
>   in _new_conn(self)
>
> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'

So I updated my requests like below

```
pip install requests --upgrade
```

But it still throws the same error.Any help is appreciated .

Comment: Do you mind to share a full [mcve](/help/mcve)? In any case plotly offline is not needed anymore.

Comment: @rpanai is the above ok?